# Empty cell vs empty string in imported file

Tags: excel, csv, null, vba

In short, I'm importing a CSV file into an excel sheet and would like to be able to tell the difference between a cell that's in the CSV with no data, and a cell that isn't in the CSV.

For example, let the following be text in the file "test.csv"

```
1,2,3,4
5,,7,
9,10
13,14,15,16
```

Then, in a VBA macro, I load this file as a query table (code largely copied from http://www.zerrtech.com/content/excel-vba-open-csv-file-and-import):

```
With Sheet1.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;test.csv", _
  Destination:=Sheet1.Range("A1"))
    .Name = "Table1"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Which loads the CSV into cells as follows:

```
   |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
 1 |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |
---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
 2 |  5  |     |  7  |     |
---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
 3 |  9  |  10 |     |     |
---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
 4 |  13 |  14 |  15 |  16 |
---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

So, my question is how can I tell the difference between the empty cells B2 and D2 (which are defined to be empty in the CSV) compared to the empty cells C3 and D3 (which aren't defined in the CSV)?  If there isn't a way to do this from the loaded query table, is there a different method of importing the CSV that will accommodate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be easier ways to determine total imported values in each line, but for now:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub csvCounter()
    Const FILE_NAME As String = "C:\empty.csv"
    Const DELIM     As String = ","

    Dim fso As Object, txt As Object, dat As String, i As Long, j As Long, x As Long
    Dim lns As Long, itms As Long, itm As Variant, v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set txt = fso.OpenTextFile(FILE_NAME)
    dat = txt.ReadAll

    If InStr(dat, DELIM) > 0 And InStr(dat, vbCrLf) > 0 Then
        v1 = Split(dat, vbCrLf)                                 'split by lines
        lns = UBound(v1) + 1
        ReDim v2(1 To lns, 1 To UBound(Split(v1(0), DELIM)))    'setup final Range (array)

        For i = 1 To lns                                        'parse each line
            itm = Split(v1(i - 1), DELIM)                       'split it by delimiter
            itms = UBound(itm) + 1
            If x < itms Then
                x = itms
                ReDim Preserve v2(1 To lns, 1 To x + 1)         'resize Range to fit
            End If
            For j = 1 To itms
                v2(i, j) = itm(j - 1)                           'copy values
            Next
            v2(i, x + 1) = "Total:   " & itms                   'show count
        Next
        With Sheet1.Range("A1").Resize(lns, x + 1)
            .Value2 = v2
            .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: empty cell vs empty string]

(after importing the CSV, it might be too late to distinguish them)

Comment: Thanks, this generally works well!  I have two issues with this specific implementation though: 1) it stores the entire text file 3 times, and 2) It loses the concept of a quoted identifier.  Both of these are really just annoying, more than anything; there should be a better built-in solution!